# SOAP response/Request then how to convert it in to PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Can any one guide me the way of coding in PHP?

**Request**

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>   <soap:Header>     <UserCredentials
>   xmlns="http://LMWService/">
>   <userName>string</userName>
>   <password>string</password>     </UserCredentials>
>   </soap:Header>   <soap:Body>     <LocSingleLocation
>   xmlns="http://LMWService/">
>   <Msisdn>string</Msisdn>     </LocSingleLocation>
>   </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>

**Response**

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>   <soap:Body>     <GetLocationSingleResult
>   xmlns="http://LMWService/">
>   <Msisdn>string</Msisdn>
>   <Lat>string</Lat>       <Lon>string</Lon>
>   <Datetime>string</Datetime>
>   <Errcode>string</Errcode>
>   <Errdesc>string</Errdesc>
>   </GetLocationSingleResult>   </soap:Body>
>   </soap:Envelope>

How am I able to get POST, Host, Content-Type, Content-Length, SOAPAction regarding request/response the above ?

Comment: some sample code I am already develop but I am not be able to develop this is there any one help me out - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cb0owxww8ccuy2a/AACCCu9PeFYpBG1bdQwN-N64a?dl=0

Comment: still waiting to some one give me the proper answer?

Comment: You could try to set your request to get a XML response and, in your PHP data handling, use something like simplexml_load_file() and get data from a foreach for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP's built in SOAP client, you can obtain all the http headers such as Content-Type, Content-Length, SOAPAction, etc. by using:

```
var_dump($soapclient->__getLastRequestHeaders());
```

and

```
var_dump($soapclient->__getLastResponseHeaders());
```